# How can i apply stringify on the data which has been input by the user in an html form?

Tags: javascript, html, yaml

I have built an app using html,js and css. The output of the web app is a text or yaml file. I am inputing the data and trying to gather in a yaml file. The code is given below:-
For instance, I want the 'PDU' data in the downloaded file to be like this

> PDU:
>       PDU_IP: 10.235.250.49 (this is just a sample IP)

While I am trying to do this, its showing [object Object]. I tried to use stringify to convert object to string but failed in realizing the following funcionality. can anyone please help me in formatting the downloaded data. Basically i want the data to be in the format as it is there in a YAML file.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const extra = {};

  const oForm = document.forms.myForm;
  const oSave = document.querySelector('input[name="save"]');
  const oSub = document.querySelector('input[name="submit"]');
  const oCtrl = document.querySelector('select[name="controller"]');
  const oTest = document.querySelector('select[name="test"]');
  const oProto = document.querySelector('select[name="protocol"]');
  const oTmp = document.querySelector('template');


  const changehandler = function(e) {
    let option = this.options[this.options.selectedIndex];

    if (option.hasAttribute('data-extra')) extra[this.name] = this.value;
    else {
      if (extra.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) delete extra[this.name];
    }

    if (Object.keys(extra).length == 2) {
      let fieldset = oTmp.content.cloneNode(true);
      oForm.insertBefore(fieldset, oProto.parentNode.nextSibling)
    } else {
      if (document.getElementById('extra')) {
        fieldset = document.getElementById('extra')
        fieldset.parentNode.removeChild(fieldset);
      }
    }

    if (option.hasAttribute('data-extra')) extra[this.name] = this.value;
    else {
      if (extra.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) delete extra[this.name];
    }


    if (this.name == 'controller') {
      if (this.value == 'RAID') oProto.disabled = false
      else oProto.disabled = true
    }
  }



  const dialog = function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
    return false;
  }




  const savehandler = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let valid = true;

    /*[ 'name','email','test','controller','ip','chassis' ].forEach( n => {
     oForm[ n ].classList.remove('invalid');
     if( oForm[ n ].value=='' ){
      oForm[ n ].classList.add('invalid');
      valid=false; 
     }
    });*/
    if (!valid) return dialog('Please fill all the fields!');



    const ipformat = /^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/;
    if (ipformat.test(oForm.ip.value) == false) {
      return dialog('Invalid IP Address');
    }



    let data = {
      "PDU": {
        "PDU TEST": oForm.test.value,
        "PDU_IP": oForm.ip.value
      },
      'Product Type': oForm.controller.value,
      'Protocol Type': oForm.protocol.value,
      'Chasis Inputs': oForm.chassis.value
    };
    var datastr = JSON.stringify(data);

    if (Object.keys(extra).length == 2) {
      data[' -  #Controller_ID_A'] = oForm['Controller-ID1'].value;
      data['   HBA_Ports_A'] = [oForm['hba-ports1'].value];
      data['   MC_IP_A'] = oForm['extra-ip1'].value;
      data['   MC_Netmask_A'] = oForm['netmask-ip1'].value;
      data['   MC_Gateway_A'] = oForm['gateway-ip1'].value;
      data['   MC_A'] = oForm['rbod-mc1'].value;
      data['   SC_A'] = oForm['rbod-sc1'].value;
      data['   FU_A'] = oForm['rbod-fu1'].value;
      data['   EC_A'] = oForm['rbod-ec1'].value;


    }


    if (Object.keys(extra).length == 2) {
      data[' -  #Controller_ID'] = oForm['Controller-ID'].value;
      data['    HBA_Ports'] = [oForm['hba-ports'].value];
      data['    MC_IP'] = oForm['extra-ip'].value;
      data['    MC_Netmask'] = oForm['netmask-ip'].value;
      data['    MC_Gateway'] = oForm['gateway-ip'].value;
      data['    MC'] = oForm['rbod-mc'].value;
      data['    SC'] = oForm['rbod-sc'].value;
      data['    FU'] = oForm['rbod-fu'].value;
      data['    EC'] = oForm['rbod-ec'].value;


    }



    let payload = Object.keys(data).map(key => {
      return [key, data[key]].join(': ')
    }).join(String.fromCharCode(10));


    const blob = new Blob([payload], {
      type: 'text/plain'
    });
    const file = 'formData.yaml';

    let link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = file;

    if (window.webkitURL != null) {
      link.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob);
    } else {
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.style.display = "none";
      document.body.appendChild(link);
    }
    link.click();
  }


  oCtrl.addEventListener('change', changehandler);
  oTest.addEventListener('change', changehandler);
  oSave.addEventListener('click', savehandler);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Save form Data in a Text File using JavaScript</title>
  <h1>User Information </h1>
  <style>
    html,
    html * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border-color: teal;
      font-family: calibri;
    }
    
    html {
      background: radial-gradient(rgba(48, 97, 97, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5))
    }
    
    input[type=button],
    input[type=submit] {
      padding: 1rem;
    }
    
    input[type=text],
    textarea,
    select {
      font: 17px Calibri;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 12px;
      border: 1px solid rgb(19, 18, 18);
      border-radius: 4px;
      color: teal
    }
    
    fieldset {
      border: none;
      padding: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
      color: rgb(16, 8, 32);
      font-size: 25px;
      font-style: initial;
      font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    }
    
    #extra {
      border: 2px solid black;
      background: whitesmoke;
      border-radius: 1rem;
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
      width: calc(100% - 24px);
      margin: auto;
      float: none;
      clear: both;
      text-indent: 50px;
    }
    
    #extra h6 {
      margin: 0
    }
    
    #extra style .invalid {
      border: 2px solid red!important;
      background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)
    }
  </style>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <template>
   <fieldset id='extra'>
    <h6>Additional Details Required</h6>
    <label for='Controller_ID_A'>Controller_ID:</label>
     <select name='Controller-ID1' required>
     <option value=""> - Select the Controller ID - </option>
     <option value='A'>A </select>
    <label for='HBA_Ports_A'>HBA_Ports:</label><input type='text' name='hba-ports1' placeholder='Enter the HBA Ports' /> 
    <label for='MC_IP_A'>MC_IP:</label><input type='text' name='extra-ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_IP' /> 
    <label for='MC_Netmask_A'>MC_Netmask:</label><input type='text' name='netmask-ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_Netmask' /> 
    <label for='MC_Gateway_A'>MC_Gateway:</label><input type='text' name='gateway-ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_Gateway' /> 
    <label for='MC_A'>MC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod-mc1' placeholder='Enter the MC Port' /> 
    <label for='SC_A'>SC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod-sc1' placeholder='Enter the SC Port' /> 
    <label for='FU_A'>FU:</label><input type='text' name='rbod-fu1' placeholder='Enter the FU Port' /> 
    <label for='EC_A'>EC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod-ec1' placeholder='Enter the EC Port' /> 

    <label for='Controller_ID'>Controller_ID:</label>
    <select name='Controller-ID' required>
    <option value=""> - Select the Controller ID - </option>
    <option value='B'>B </select>
   <label for='HBA_Ports'>HBA_Ports:</label><input type='text' name='hba-ports' placeholder='Enter the HBA Ports' /> 
   <label for='MC_IP'>MC_IP:</label><input type='text' name='extra-ip' placeholder='Enter the MC_IP' /> 
   <label for='MC_Netmask'>MC_Netmask:</label><input type='text' name='netmask-ip' placeholder='Enter the MC_Netmask' /> 
   <label for='MC_Gateway'>MC_Gateway:</label><input type='text' name='gateway-ip' placeholder='Enter the MC_Gateway' /> 
   <label for='MC'>MC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod-mc' placeholder='Enter the MC Port' /> 
   <label for='SC'>SC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod-sc' placeholder='Enter the SC Port' /> 
   <label for='FU'>FU:</label><input type='text' name='rbod-fu' placeholder='Enter the FU Port' /> 
   <label for='EC'>EC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod-ec' placeholder='Enter the EC Port' /> 
    
   </fieldset>
  </template>



  <form name='myForm' method='POST'>

    <fieldset>
      <label for='Controller Type'>Controller Type</label>
      <select name='controller' required>
        <option value=""> - Select the Controller - </option>
        <option data-extra=true value='RAID'>RAID
          <option data-extra=true value='JBOD'>JBOD
            <option data-extra=true value='AP'>AP
      </select>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <label for='Test Type'>Test Type</label>
      <select name='test' required>
        <option value=""> - Select The Test - </option>
        <option data-extra=true value='BFT'>BFT
          <option data-extra=true value='CTO'>CTO
            <option data-extra=true value='RAID Generic'>RAID Generic
              <option data-extra=true value='Port Check'>Port Check
                <option data-extra=true value='FW Generic'>FW Generic
                  <option data-extra=true value='JBOD Generic'>JBOD Generic
      </select>
    </fieldset>

    <!-- insert templated additional details here -->

    <fieldset>
      <label for='Protocol Type'>Protocol Type</label>
      <select name='protocol' required>
        <option value=""> - Select The Protocol -
          <option data-extra=true value='SAS'>SAS
            <option data-extra=true value='iSCSI'>iSCSI
              <option data-extra=true value='FC'>FC
      </select>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <label for='IP Address'>IP Address:</label>
      <input type='text' name='ip' placeholder='Enter your IP address' required />
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <label for='Chasis Input'>Number of Chasis Input:</label>
      <input type='number' name='chassis' placeholder='Enter Number of Chasis' required />
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <input type='button' name='save' value='Save data to file' />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this snippet. It's mostly your code, but I changed the part where you create the `payload`.

I marked my changes with `MY CHANGE BEGINS HERE` and `MY CHANGE ENDS HERE` comments.

It adds spaces dynamically, so the format looks like this:

```
PDU:
  PDU TEST: BFT
  PDU_IP: 185.237.96.51
Product Type: 
Protocol Type: iSCSI
Chasis Inputs:
```

However, it does not work with the rest of your fields, but maybe you can use it to replace your hacky whitespacing by creating plain objects and adding them to your `data`.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const extra = {};

  const oForm = document.forms.myForm;
  const oSave = document.querySelector('input[name="save"]');
  const oSub = document.querySelector('input[name="submit"]');
  const oCtrl = document.querySelector('select[name="controller"]');
  const oTest = document.querySelector('select[name="test"]');
  const oProto = document.querySelector('select[name="protocol"]');
  const oTmp = document.querySelector('template');


  const changehandler = function(e) {
    let option = this.options[this.options.selectedIndex];

    if (option.hasAttribute('data-extra')) extra[this.name] = this.value;
    else {
      if (extra.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) delete extra[this.name];
    }

    if (Object.keys(extra).length == 2) {
      let fieldset = oTmp.content.cloneNode(true);
      oForm.insertBefore(fieldset, oProto.parentNode.nextSibling)
    } else {
      if (document.getElementById('extra')) {
        fieldset = document.getElementById('extra')
        fieldset.parentNode.removeChild(fieldset);
      }
    }

    if (option.hasAttribute('data-extra')) extra[this.name] = this.value;
    else {
      if (extra.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) delete extra[this.name];
    }


    if (this.name == 'controller') {
      if (this.value == 'RAID') oProto.disabled = false
      else oProto.disabled = true
    }
  }



  const dialog = function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
    return false;
  }




  const savehandler = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let valid = true;

    /*[ 'name','email','test','controller','ip','chassis' ].forEach( n => {
     oForm[ n ].classList.remove('invalid');
     if( oForm[ n ].value=='' ){
      oForm[ n ].classList.add('invalid');
      valid=false; 
     }
    });*/
    if (!valid) return dialog('Please fill all the fields!');



    const ipformat = /^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/;
    if (ipformat.test(oForm.ip.value) == false) {
      return dialog('Invalid IP Address');
    }



    let data = {
      "PDU": {
        "PDU TEST": oForm.test.value,
        "PDU_IP": oForm.ip.value
      },
      'Product Type': oForm.controller.value,
      'Protocol Type': oForm.protocol.value,
      'Chasis Inputs': oForm.chassis.value
    };
    var datastr = JSON.stringify(data);

    if (Object.keys(extra).length == 2) {
      data[' -  #Controller_ID_A'] = oForm['Controller-ID1'].value;
      data['   HBA_Ports_A'] = [oForm['hba-ports1'].value];
      data['   MC_IP_A'] = oForm['extra-ip1'].value;
      data['   MC_Netmask_A'] = oForm['netmask-ip1'].value;
      data['   MC_Gateway_A'] = oForm['gateway-ip1'].value;
      data['   MC_A'] = oForm['rbod-mc1'].value;
      data['   SC_A'] = oForm['rbod-sc1'].value;
      data['   FU_A'] = oForm['rbod-fu1'].value;
      data['   EC_A'] = oForm['rbod-ec1'].value;


    }


    if (Object.keys(extra).length == 2) {
      data[' -  #Controller_ID'] = oForm['Controller-ID'].value;
      data['    HBA_Ports'] = [oForm['hba-ports'].value];
      data['    MC_IP'] = oForm['extra-ip'].value;
      data['    MC_Netmask'] = oForm['netmask-ip'].value;
      data['    MC_Gateway'] = oForm['gateway-ip'].value;
      data['    MC'] = oForm['rbod-mc'].value;
      data['    SC'] = oForm['rbod-sc'].value;
      data['    FU'] = oForm['rbod-fu'].value;
      data['    EC'] = oForm['rbod-ec'].value;


    }


    // MY CHANGE BEGINS HERE <-------
    let payload = '';
    const addToPayload = (object, whitespace) => {
      for (const key of Object.keys(object)) {
        payload += whitespace + key + ':';
        const value = object[key];
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
          payload += String.fromCharCode(10);
          addToPayload(value, whitespace + '  ');
        } else {
          payload += ' ' + value + String.fromCharCode(10);
        }
      }
    }
    addToPayload(data, '');
    // MY CHANGE ENDS HERE <------------


    const blob = new Blob([payload], {
      type: 'text/plain'
    });
    const file = 'formData.yaml';

    let link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = file;

    if (window.webkitURL != null) {
      link.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob);
    } else {
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.style.display = "none";
      document.body.appendChild(link);
    }
    link.click();
  }


  oCtrl.addEventListener('change', changehandler);
  oTest.addEventListener('change', changehandler);
  oSave.addEventListener('click', savehandler);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Save form Data in a Text File using JavaScript</title>
  <h1>User Information </h1>
  <style>
    html,
    html * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border-color: teal;
      font-family: calibri;
    }
    
    html {
      background: radial-gradient(rgba(48, 97, 97, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5))
    }
    
    input[type=button],
    input[type=submit] {
      padding: 1rem;
    }
    
    input[type=text],
    textarea,
    select {
      font: 17px Calibri;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 12px;
      border: 1px solid rgb(19, 18, 18);
      border-radius: 4px;
      color: teal
    }
    
    fieldset {
      border: none;
      padding: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
      color: rgb(16, 8, 32);
      font-size: 25px;
      font-style: initial;
      font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    }
    
    #extra {
      border: 2px solid black;
      background: whitesmoke;
      border-radius: 1rem;
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
      width: calc(100% - 24px);
      margin: auto;
      float: none;
      clear: both;
      text-indent: 50px;
    }
    
    #extra h6 {
      margin: 0
    }
    
    #extra style .invalid {
      border: 2px solid red!important;
      background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)
    }
  </style>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <template>
   <fieldset id='extra'>
    <h6>Additional Details Required</h6>
    <label for='Controller_ID_A'>Controller_ID:</label>
     <select name='Controller-ID1' required>
     <option value=""> - Select the Controller ID - </option>
     <option value='A'>A </select>
    <label for='HBA_Ports_A'>HBA_Ports:</label><input type='text' name='hba-ports1' placeholder='Enter the HBA Ports' /> 
    <label for='MC_IP_A'>MC_IP:</label><input type='text' name='extra-ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_IP' /> 
    <label for='MC_Netmask_A'>MC_Netmask:</label><input type='text' name='netmask-ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_Netmask' /> 
    <label for='MC_Gateway_A'>MC_Gateway:</label><input type='text' name='gateway-ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_Gateway' /> 
    <label for='MC_A'>MC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod-mc1' placeholder='Enter the MC Port' /> 
    <label for='SC_A'>SC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod-sc1' placeholder='Enter the SC Port' /> 
    <label for='FU_A'>FU:</label><input type='text' name='rbod-fu1' placeholder='Enter the FU Port' /> 
    <label for='EC_A'>EC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod-ec1' placeholder='Enter the EC Port' /> 

    <label for='Controller_ID'>Controller_ID:</label>
    <select name='Controller-ID' required>
    <option value=""> - Select the Controller ID - </option>
    <option value='B'>B </select>
   <label for='HBA_Ports'>HBA_Ports:</label><input type='text' name='hba-ports' placeholder='Enter the HBA Ports' /> 
   <label for='MC_IP'>MC_IP:</label><input type='text' name='extra-ip' placeholder='Enter the MC_IP' /> 
   <label for='MC_Netmask'>MC_Netmask:</label><input type='text' name='netmask-ip' placeholder='Enter the MC_Netmask' /> 
   <label for='MC_Gateway'>MC_Gateway:</label><input type='text' name='gateway-ip' placeholder='Enter the MC_Gateway' /> 
   <label for='MC'>MC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod-mc' placeholder='Enter the MC Port' /> 
   <label for='SC'>SC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod-sc' placeholder='Enter the SC Port' /> 
   <label for='FU'>FU:</label><input type='text' name='rbod-fu' placeholder='Enter the FU Port' /> 
   <label for='EC'>EC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod-ec' placeholder='Enter the EC Port' /> 
    
   </fieldset>
  </template>



  <form name='myForm' method='POST'>

    <fieldset>
      <label for='Controller Type'>Controller Type</label>
      <select name='controller' required>
        <option value=""> - Select the Controller - </option>
        <option data-extra=true value='RAID'>RAID
          <option data-extra=true value='JBOD'>JBOD
            <option data-extra=true value='AP'>AP
      </select>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <label for='Test Type'>Test Type</label>
      <select name='test' required>
        <option value=""> - Select The Test - </option>
        <option data-extra=true value='BFT'>BFT
          <option data-extra=true value='CTO'>CTO
            <option data-extra=true value='RAID Generic'>RAID Generic
              <option data-extra=true value='Port Check'>Port Check
                <option data-extra=true value='FW Generic'>FW Generic
                  <option data-extra=true value='JBOD Generic'>JBOD Generic
      </select>
    </fieldset>

    <!-- insert templated additional details here -->

    <fieldset>
      <label for='Protocol Type'>Protocol Type</label>
      <select name='protocol' required>
        <option value=""> - Select The Protocol -
          <option data-extra=true value='SAS'>SAS
            <option data-extra=true value='iSCSI'>iSCSI
              <option data-extra=true value='FC'>FC
      </select>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <label for='IP Address'>IP Address:</label>
      <input type='text' name='ip' placeholder='Enter your IP address' required />
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <label for='Chasis Input'>Number of Chasis Input:</label>
      <input type='number' name='chassis' placeholder='Enter Number of Chasis' required />
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <input type='button' name='save' value='Save data to file' />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

---

You commented that you would prefer dynamic filenames. You can replace

```
const file = 'formData.yaml';
```

with something like this:

```
let file = 'test_' + data.PDU['PDU TEST'];
file += '_controller_' + data['Product Type'];
file += '_' + new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10); // '2020-05-02'
file += '.yaml';
file = prompt('Filename:', file); // to edit manually
if (!file) { return; } // canceled by user
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help @Stratubas. Although while the other changes have been successfully applied the field 'HBA_Ports' is append with a 0 and the data is showing in the next line. can you help me fix this?

Comment: @Jayashri I guess you are using an unnecessary array there, so that 0 is the index (of the only item). Try to fix it, then if you can't, update your question with the code you've done so far and I'll take a look when I can.

Comment: Thanks a lot @stratubas I was able to manipulate my code to get the desired format

Comment: is it possible to rename the file which I am downloading in the end. Or else can we set a dynamic name which could be a combination of 'test_type'+'Controller_type'?